# Fail to make directory in C#

Tags: c#, directory

Below is my code to create a directory in my PC.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DirectoryInfo dataDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\CsharpData");
            Console.WriteLine(dataDir.Attributes);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But, the result looks like this.

Attribute is equal to -1, and I can't get my desired directory.

Can anyone let me know what my mistake is?

[image]

Comment: The `DirectoryInfo` constructor doesn't create directories. Are you looking for its `Create` method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.create?view=net-5.0

Comment: It works(dataDir.Create();). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code. You need to use create ,ethod for creating the directory.

```
DirectoryInfo dataDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\CsharpData");

if(!dataDir.Exists)
{
    dataDir.Create();
}
System.Console.WriteLine(dataDir.Attributes);

System.Console.ReadLine();
```